# prototypejs observe IE7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7, click, prototypejs, observer-pattern

I a have a link where I want to redefine the action onclick. I have to use Prototype as framework. So I use the function observe.

```
<a id="mylink" href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('mylink').writeAttribute('onclick', 'return false');
$('mylink').observe('click', function () { /* do some stuff */ return false; });
</script>
```

This code is working for mostly all browser, but IE7 style making the redirect after what. Do you know how to stop this redirection?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('mylink').observe('click', function(event) {
    /* do some stuff */
    event.stop();
    return false;
});
```